# c# code issue in .net application

Tags: c#, .net

Below code return false if more than one usb device is connected (at least one containing key) .

I want to make this code to return true if one of connected usb device has key,

```
List<DriveInfo> list = new List<DriveInfo>(DriveInfo.GetDrives());

foreach (DriveInfo drive in list)
{
   if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
   {
       if ((File.Exists(drive.RootDirectory + "Key.txt")) && 
           File.Exists(drive.RootDirectory + "SerialNumber.txt"))
       {
           string KeyFromUsb = (System.IO.File.ReadAllText(drive.RootDirectory + "Key.txt"));
           string serialusb = (System.IO.File.ReadAllText(drive.RootDirectory + "SerialNumber.txt"));
           int serialNumbeFromUsb = Convert.ToInt32(serialusb);
           string KeyFromDataBase = FoundKey(serialNumbeFromUsb);

           if (KeyFromDataBase == KeyFromUsb)
           {
              ok = true;
           }
           else
           {
               return false;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as your conditions are not satisfied, the code returns always false, but you're not returning true. Maybe modifying the line `ok = true;` to `return true;` could help?

Comment: the foreach loop exit once return false in else statement. hence your problem of if more than 1 usb devices are connected. consider setting a "flag" and move your if statement for the "flag" outside the foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very common logic problem.

Change `ok = true` to `return true` and move `return false` to the outside of the loop.

```
List<DriveInfo> list = new List<DriveInfo>(DriveInfo.GetDrives());

foreach (DriveInfo drive in list)
{
   if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
   {
       if ((File.Exists(drive.RootDirectory + "Key.txt")) && 
           File.Exists(drive.RootDirectory + "SerialNumber.txt"))
       {
           string KeyFromUsb = (System.IO.File.ReadAllText(drive.RootDirectory + "Key.txt"));
           string serialusb = (System.IO.File.ReadAllText(drive.RootDirectory + "SerialNumber.txt"));
           int serialNumbeFromUsb = Convert.ToInt32(serialusb);
           string KeyFromDataBase = FoundKey(serialNumbeFromUsb);

           if (KeyFromDataBase == KeyFromUsb)
           {
              return true;
           }
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DriveInfo> list = new List<DriveInfo>(DriveInfo.GetDrives());
//var i = 0;
int i = 0;
foreach (DriveInfo drive in list)
{
   if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
   {
       if ((File.Exists(drive.RootDirectory + "Key.txt")) && 
           File.Exists(drive.RootDirectory + "SerialNumber.txt"))
       {
           string KeyFromUsb = (System.IO.File.ReadAllText(drive.RootDirectory + "Key.txt"));
           string serialusb = (System.IO.File.ReadAllText(drive.RootDirectory + "SerialNumber.txt"));
           int serialNumbeFromUsb = Convert.ToInt32(serialusb);
           string KeyFromDataBase = FoundKey(serialNumbeFromUsb);

           if (KeyFromDataBase == KeyFromUsb)
           {
              i = 1; //or simply return true, this will exit the loop
           }
        }
    }
}

if(i == 1)
{
    ok = true;
}
```

or simply return true. (do not return false in foreach loop).

Answer (score 0):

```
      List<DriveInfo> list = new List<DriveInfo>(DriveInfo.GetDrives());
      var condSatisfied = false;

      foreach (DriveInfo drive in list)
      {
          if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
          {
              if ((File.Exists(drive.RootDirectory + "Key.txt")) && 
                 File.Exists(drive.RootDirectory + "SerialNumber.txt"))
               {
                   string KeyFromUsb = (System.IO.File.ReadAllText(drive.RootDirectory + "Key.txt"));
                   string serialusb = (System.IO.File.ReadAllText(drive.RootDirectory + "SerialNumber.txt"));
                 int serialNumbeFromUsb = Convert.ToInt32(serialusb);
                   string KeyFromDataBase = FoundKey(serialNumbeFromUsb);

                   if (KeyFromDataBase == KeyFromUsb)
                  {
                      ok = true;
                     condSatisfied = true;
                   }
               }
           }
        }

       return condSatisfied
```